# How to show notification for user for particular period only in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

> I am having one table with `end_date` and `due_date`. if users
>   `end_date` is `2018-02-01` and `due_date` is `2018-04-30`. then how to
>   write query that user can see his notification for `end_date`  from
>   `end_date's` next month i.e `10-march` till `due_date`.

my current query shows me all data.

```
$Records = "SELECT     *, 
           DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS end_date,
           DATE_FORMAT(due_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS due_date,
           ORG_NAME 
FROM       vat_quarters 
LEFT JOIN  organizations 
ON         vat_quarters.org_id = organizations.org_id";
```

**if `end_date` is current_month then notification will start to display from next_month's 10th day till his `due_date`.
if `end_date` is `march` then notification will start to display from `april's` 10th day till `due_date`.**

Comment: It would help if you added the table definitions.